# Detect the User Visibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

My program need to detect the user visibility, if the user is login or not. I Put the information on the database

here the pseudocode:

if the user click "LOGIN" I Update the user information to ONLINE = TRUE;

else if the user click "LOGOUT"  I Update the user information to ONLINE = FALSE;

My Question is: How can I detect if the user leave the website or turn off the computer without cllicking "logout"

thanks best wishes

Comment: Google 'ASP.NET Authentication'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do so by tracking the last activity of the User and simply displaying online for a user if the user has activity in the last minute(s).

In addition to this, you could have a polling mechanism with JavaScript to keep updating this value every minute or so the user has the webpage open by sending a request using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect user activity just on a server side. Because if user just logged in it doesn't says anything: he can clear cookies right next second and login one more time, and more and more.

As i see it you need to have some js code on a client side wich does request to server if each N seconds saying: the user is still logged in and using current browser page and/or doing some actions. Once server has no requests from some user e.g. for 5xN seconds - you can mark that user as inactive/offline

Comment: Hi to All thanks for your response; I thinking of using signalr or global.asax and use the session_end .... is this possible?